# Optimizing Node and socket.io on NGINX Proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I'm attempting to scale a Node.js application but am a little confused on one piece of it.  I moved all my static files to the gateway server running NGINX, and it routes them accordingly.  Now looking at the waterfall diagram in Chrome's dev tools, I notice a full second of wait time to access the socket.io javascript file.  I'm assuming that is because this is still being accessed from the application server, not the web server.  My question is, can I move this file to the web server to have it load faster?  It's an npm module so it seems a little fishy to me, like it needs some sort of interaction with the application server to initialize the connection or something.  Or am I thinking about this all wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can move, it is kept in package, so that when package fixes, you get the latest one. So as long as you keep it in sync it should work